# c# How Save text file line to line

Tags: .net, vb.net, filestream

I am success save file but I need 1st save after when click 2nd save then going 2nd line.

but it's show all same line.

Can you help me how I am doing 2nd line?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = "E:\\sumon.txt";
        string textToAdd = textBox1.Text;

       using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName, false))
        {
            writer.Write(textToAdd);

       }

    }
```

Comment: `StreamReader` is a *reader,* not a *writer.*  If you want to write, you need a `StreamWriter`.

Comment: Why would a reader have a write? Perhaps you want a `StreamWriter`? Also, indentation is your friend.

Comment: please guys - don't downvote new users without any comment of why

Answer (score 6):

Use a StreamWriter, not a StreamReader. Try the following:

```
using(StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter("yourfilename.txt"))
{
    sr.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
}
```

The `using` keyword here allows the compiler to automatically dispose of the writer when it falls out of scope, which includes closing the stream and releasing the underlying operating system resources.

Comment: +1 for the using tip for beginners

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply use

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("yourfilename.txt", textBox1.Text);
```